# シェルスクリプトでapt-getのY/nを手動で打ち込まなくてもよいようにしたい

Tags: ubuntu, apt

a.sh

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

というシェルスクリプトを書きました.
ここで、Y/nと聞かれるのですがこれを自動化したいのですがどのような方法がありますか。

【追記】

```
sudo apt-get install hogehoge
```

の場合はどうしましょう

Comment: もしご自身でお困りではないのでしたら，ご自身で回答することも[奨励されています](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) よ．邪推でしたら（あるいは意図があってそうなさっていないなら）申し訳ないです．

Comment: Opencv だとコードが長いじゃないですか面倒なのでほげほげで打ち込んだのです。

Comment: @Yosh 
信用度が 15 を超えていて、すでに回答を知っている場合、回答は知りませんし信用度は１ですよ

Comment: あ，信用度については失念していました，すみません．又回答についても僕の考え違いなのですね．重ねてごめんなさい．今の自分は困ってないけどスタック・オーバーフローで情報を共有しておきたいという場合もあって，それはそれでいいことなので，そちらなのかなと思ってしまいました．

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

Comment: `--yes`のほか`--force-yes`もあります。

Answer (score 2):

情報として:

yと答えればよい場合、汎用的なのは `yes | ...` ですかね。(y以外にも出来ます)

Answer (score 1):

update / upgrade / install どの場合も `-y` で大丈夫です。`man apt-get` にも以下のように書かれています。

> **-y, --yes, --assume-yes**
>   プロンプトへの自動承諾 - すべてのプロンプトに自動的に "yes" と答え、非対話的に実行します。保留したパッケージの状態を変更したり、必須パッケージを削除するような不適切な状況の場合、apt-getは処理を中断します。設定項目: APT::Get::Assume-Yes